# Flagging a question if I don't have high enough reputation

Tags: support, reputation, flags

I am currently getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.” when I try to ask a question and have tried my best to edit my questions and have gotten rid of the the poor ones. I have recently tried fixing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790891/how-to-sort-a-3-dimensional-array-by-a-key-in-php), and have made a case as to why it is not a duplicate, but since I do not have a high enough reputation, I cannot flag it for a moderator to reevaluate it.

I am trying to lift the ban on my account and it seems editing my questions is not enough as noted from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) in the Help Center. Because I am very new to this site, I wasn't aware of many of the full particulars and conventions of the Stack Exchange sites. I am making an earnest effort to lift the ban on my account and do not have the clout to flag a question because my reputation is not high enough. What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: I suppose mentioning it on meta may work in a pinch...

Comment: Suggest some edits. You only need another four points.

Comment: Smite all the typos!

Comment: Ah, my mistake I just fixed it! The ban was only for questions.

Comment: Deleting some of those questions is not helping you - undelete and improve them. Deleted questions still count, and you can't improve deleted questions...